# How to navigate through a editable ComboBox options with arrow keys in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have the next ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox
   behaviours:ComboBoxBehavior.CharacterCasing="Upper"
   IsEditable="True" 
   SelectedItem="{Binding Enfermedad}"
   IsTextSearchEnabled="false" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Enfermedades}" 
   Text="{Binding Texto ,Mode=TwoWay}"
   Style="{StaticResource EditableComboBoxStyle}">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
         <i:InvokeCommandAction 
            Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.EnfermedadEnCatalogoCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

All I want is to navigate trough the options with the arrows and with Enter or with a mouse click to select the item. Now the default behavior is when a use the arrows, it automatically selects the item. How can I do this? I have searched for a lot of post here in StackOverflow but no one seems to work for my case.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior is realized by triggers, that will highlight the currently selected item.

You can defer selection by setting the source property `Enfermedad` explicitly on key press. The cleanest way would be to implement a simple attached behavior.
Since the following behavior targets `Selector`, it can handle every `ItemsControl`, not only `ComboBox`:

**Selector.cs**
The property `Selector.AcceptedItem` is configured to bind `TwoWay` by default.
The property `Selector.AcceptKey` allows any value of the `Key` enumeration. Setting this property to `Key.None` will make the attaching `ItemsControl` behave normal (change `Selector.AcceptedItem` on navigation). Not setting `Selector.AcceptKey` at all will disable the behavior.

```
class Selector : DependencyObject
{
  #region AcceptKey attached property

  public static readonly DependencyProperty AcceptKeyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "AcceptKey",
    typeof(Key),
    typeof(Selector),
    new PropertyMetadata(Key.NoName, Selector.OnAcceptKeyChanged));

  public static void SetAcceptKey(DependencyObject attachingElement, Key value) =>
    attachingElement.SetValue(Selector.AcceptKeyProperty, value);

  public static Key GetAcceptKey(DependencyObject attachingElement) =>
    (Key) attachingElement.GetValue(Selector.AcceptKeyProperty);

  #endregion

  #region AcceptedItem attached property

  public static readonly DependencyProperty AcceptedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "AcceptedItem",
    typeof(object),
    typeof(Selector),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
      default,
      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
      Selector.OnAcceptedItemChanged));

  public static void SetAcceptedItem(DependencyObject attachingElement, object value) =>
    attachingElement.SetValue(Selector.AcceptedItemProperty, value);

  public static object GetAcceptedItem(DependencyObject attachingElement) =>
    attachingElement.GetValue(Selector.AcceptedItemProperty);

  #endregion


  private static void OnAcceptKeyChanged(
    DependencyObject attachingElement,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (!(attachingElement is System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector selector))
    {
      throw new ArgumentException("Attaching element must be of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector'");
    }

    StartHandlingKeyPress(selector);
  }

  // Update data source (TwoWay binding)
  private static void OnAcceptedItemChanged(DependencyObject attachingElement, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (attachingElement is System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector selector)
    {
      selector.SelectedItem = e.NewValue;
    }
  }

  private static void StartHandlingKeyPress(UIElement uiElement)
  {
    WeakEventManager<UIElement, KeyEventArgs>.AddHandler(
      uiElement,
      nameof(UIElement.PreviewKeyUp),
      Selector.HandleKeyPress);
  }

  private static void StopHandlingKeyPress(UIElement uiElement)
  {
    WeakEventManager<UIElement, KeyEventArgs>.RemoveHandler(
      uiElement,
      nameof(UIElement.PreviewKeyUp),
      Selector.HandleKeyPress);
  }

  private static void HandleKeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
    var attachedSelector = sender as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector;
    Key acceptKey = Selector.GetAcceptKey(attachedSelector);
    if (acceptKey == Key.None || acceptKey == e.Key)
    {
      Selector.SetAcceptedItem(attachedSelector, attachedSelector.SelectedItem);
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <ComboBox Selector.AcceptKey="{x:Static Key.Enter}"
            Selector.AcceptedItem="{Binding Enfermedad}" />
</Window>
```

Comment: It throw me error when compiling saying that NotNull doesn't exists and with the  new `FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
      default,
      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
      Selector.OnAcceptedItemChanged)` part of the code

Comment: You have to remove the `[NotNull]` attributes from the get/set methods (or import the attribute via Nuget, e.g. JetBrains). I have removed them from the example code. It should compile now.

Comment: And wait I do with the `new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            default,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
            Selector.OnAcceptedItemChanged))` errors for default it says `default literal is not avaiable in C# 7`, for ` FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault` it says `cannot convert from PropertyMetadataOptions to  PropertyChangedCallback`

Comment: And for `Selector.OnAcceptedItemChanged` cannot convert the method group to CoerceValueCallback

Comment: I was not aware of the language version you are using. You can replace `default` with `default(object)`.

Comment: I'm using this constuctor `FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Object, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions, PropertyChangedCallback)`. I think it should work once you fixed the `default` keyword,

Comment: Yes, but didn't work for the navigation with the arrows

Comment: It does. I have tested it. Have you copied my code? Have you set the `AcceptKey` on the `ComboBox` element? It could be: `Selector.AcceptKey="{x:Static Key.Enter}"`.

Comment: Also remove the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` binding. This is handled by the behavior. Only bind to `Selector.AcceptedItem`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216750/discussion-between-bioniccode-and-paul-miranda).